# Descargar y analizar hoja de calculo spreadsheet con javascript

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo, fetch

necesito descargar una hoja de calculo hecha con spreadsheets como csv y poder usar la información con javascript. Tengo este código:

```
function fetchCSV () {
 let src = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/GZ5l45JT9VV-y/pub?gid=1670264290&single=true&output=csv"
 fetch(src, {
  headers: new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
 }),
 mode: 'no-cors'
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
 console.log(data)
})
}
document.addEventListener('load',fetchCSV())
```

No puedo acceder a la información del CSV ni utilizando reponse.text() ni response.blob(), pero en herramientas de desarrollador si puedo ver el contenido del csv.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo acceder al contenido del archivo csv?.

Comment: si usas `'no-cors'` no puedes leer el archivo usando fetch.